# Insert whitespace between characters in listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I am trying to insert items into a listbox in my asp.net C# application

I concatenate some values and put whitespace in between them but it doesn't show up in the listbox.

```
        ListItem lt = new ListItem();
        lt.Text = ItemName + "    " + barcode + "    " + price; // problem
        lt.Value = barcode;
        lstMailItems.Items.Add(lt);
```

i even tried

```
lt.Text = ItemName + "\t\t" + barcode + "\t\t" + price; // problem
lt.Text = ItemName + "& nbsp;" + barcode + "& nbsp;" + price; // &nbsp shows up as text
```

but that even doesn't seem to work. How can I put whitespace between these strings so that it shows up in the listbox as well

Comment: I have checked from browser rendered HTML, spaces are generated, I think it is trimmed by browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string spaces = Server.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"); 

lt.Text = ItemName + spaces + barcode + spaces + price; // works
```

Comment: Great, I've been googling forever for this!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the above answers led me to this which worked for me.

```
string space = "&nbsp;";
                space = Server.HtmlDecode(space);
                line = line.Replace(" ", space);
                ClassCodeListBox.Items.Add(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lt.Text = string.Format("{0}\ \;{1}\ \;{2}",ItemName,barcode,price);
```

Replace \ \ with **&nbsp** If you cannot see.

Or

```
lt.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",ItemName,barcode,price);
```

Comment: @Myra: He need spaces in listitem

Comment: Are you using white-spacing attribute of css in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples that work well, and how to get the current formatted:

```
  var SaleItem = new
    {
        name = "Super Cereal",
        barcode = "0000222345",
        price = 2.55m
    };

    ListItem lt = new ListItem();
    string space = " ";
    lt.Text = String.Concat(SaleItem.name, 
        space, SaleItem.barcode, space, SaleItem.price);
    lt.Value = SaleItem.barcode;

    ListItem lt2 = new ListItem();
    lt2.Text = string.Copy(String.Format("{0}: {1} {2}", 
               SaleItem.name, SaleItem.barcode, SaleItem.price.ToString("C")));
    lt2.Value = SaleItem.barcode;

    lstMailItems.Items.Add(lt);
    lstMailItems.Items.Add(lt2);
```