# Adding white spaces to listbox item text

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I implemented according to the below link but not working :

[Insert whitespace between characters in listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237425/insert-whitespace-between-characters-in-listbox)

```
Dim spaces As String = "& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;"
                                spaces = Server.HtmlDecode(spaces)

listitem.Text = String.Concat(str1(1), spaces, str(0), spaces, str1(0))
```

Comment: the question you linked to is Asp.net is your project that or is it vb.net>

Answer (score 0):

This Working Code:

```
Dim spaces As String = Space(4)
   listbox.items.add(String.Concat("a", spaces, "B", spaces, "c"))
```

or

```
  Dim spaces As String = Space(4)
listitem.Text=String.Concat("a", spaces, "B", spaces, "c")
listbox.items.add(listitem)
```

Comment: listitem is a of listbox...your question says:Insert whitespace between characters in listbox

Comment: still not working...when i check in quick watch I can see the spaces but when it displays it's not showing....with all the above trails..

Comment: i will give you my project... in this project properly running

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Following ways

1)

```
Dim spaces As String = Space(4)
   listbox.items.add(String.Concat("a", spaces, "B", spaces, "c"))
```

2)

```
 listbox.items.add(String.Concat("a", '&nbsp;', "B", '&nbsp;', "c"))
```

3)

```
 listbox.items.add(String.Concat("a", & vbtab &, "B", & vbtab &, "c"))
```

4)

```
listbox.items.add(String.Concat("a", Chr(32) , "B", Chr(32), "c"))
```

5)

```
listbox.items.add(String.Concat("a","  " , "B", "   ", "c"))
```

None of the above is working for me....

if you change the font name you can see some difference...

### NOTE: Important thing to do in this process is to change the font name of the list box to either “Courier New” or “Lucida Console” as these are Monospaced fonts. This works only with monospaced fonts. This does not work with Times New Roman or any other Non Mono spaced fonts ;)

Answer (score 0):

listbox.items.add("a" & "    " & "B" & "   " & "c")

Try Like This

Comment: improve space in between "  " .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nonbreaking character `Chr(160)`. So your sample becomes:

```
Dim spaces As String = Chr(160) & Chr(160) & Chr(160) & Chr(160) 
listitem.Text = str1(1) & spaces & str(0) & spaces & str1(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Space As String = ("____") '(Replace the __ with spaces)
listbox1.items.add(a, space, b, space, c)
```

There are more complex ways of doing this but if you are new to coding this is the easiest way I can explain it to you.