# How to preserver white spaces in list box c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, listbox, whitespace

Hello guys currently having the following code.

I am trying to insert string array into listbox, and then to be able to
view the array data in the same list box. For some reason the white-spaces
between the string has been stripped off. How do I preserve the white-spaces while displaying
string array into listbox ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   WebReference.doOkClickExtractParams doOkClk = new WebReference.doOkClickExtractParams();
   WebReference.doOkClickExtractParamsResponse Response = extrePrmSoap.doOkClickExtractParams(doOkClk);


   ListBox1.DataSource = Response .doOkClick.namelist;
   ListBox1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237425/insert-whitespace-between-characters-in-listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In markup, you can use `&nbsp;` :

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Before&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;After" />
```

In code, you can replace spaces by unbreakable spaces for each item:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(value.Replace(" ", "\u00A0")));
```

In a database query, you can do the same with the REPLACE function:

```
SELECT 
    ...
    REPLACE(value, ' ', CHAR(160)) AS valueWithSpaces
    ...
FROM
    Clients
```

Comment: I got it now...Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `"EnableSmartParsing"` `property` to `false`

Comment: I am sorry. where I can find 'EnableSmartParsing'  property. I am using visual studio.